# Populateing ComboBox, Label, and TextBox based off of a DatagridView selection

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox, textbox, label

So i have been doing some research today trying to find information about if it is possible or not to populate a combobox (dropdown), label, and textbox based off of a datagridview selection.

By that i mean selecting a dgv row and the columns would correspond to the combo,text,and label.

is this possible or should i look at another way of doing this?

Comment: What way are you doing this?  Where are you stuck?  Show your code that doesn't work.

Comment: Ive been doing research and trying to find references about it to even see if its possible. I was trying to post photo ref of the forms im working with but it says i cant yet.

Comment: You didn't research very hard.  Start with [DataGridView.SelectionChanged Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thats because i didnt know what exactly i was looking for, that why i came to here. Thank you for the link though.